# Iterating over a struct in Golang and print the value if set

Tags: loops, go, struct

First of all, apologies if this question is confused since I'm just trying out Go and have no idea what I'm doing. I have a struct composed of a variety of attributes of different types, example:

```
type foo struct {
    bar string
    baz int
    bez []string
(...)
```

Initially I wanted to iterate over all these attributes and print the value if it existed, but I realized you cannot `range` over a struct the same way you could, say, a list or map. So I've tried out a few tricks with no luck (like trying to iterate over a separate list of attributes), and I think it's better I just ask for help because I'm probably in over my head here.

The idea is that if I create a new instance of this struct, I'd like to be able to then only print values that are set:

```
obj := foo{"bar_string", 1}
```

Given that the string slice `bez` is not set in `obj`, I'd like to be able to do something like (pseudo):

```
for i in obj:
    print i
```

Giving:

```
"bar_string"
1
```

Ideally, not printing `[]` which I guess is the zero value for `bez`.

Am I approaching this whole thing wrong? The reason I'm not using a map is because I'd like the attributes to be different types, and I'd like future differing objects I'm working in to be organized into structs for clarity.

Comment: Probably you should use reflect, but iterating over struct attributes it's wierd idea.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for a less weird idea if you want to have an object of different value types and only print the values that are set? I was under the impression that maps for example are required to have a single type.

Comment: what about map[string]interface{} ? - https://play.golang.org/p/swysnXZxvGu

Comment: @pzkpfw This seems a lot like you're trying to make go behave the way you are used to from other (non-compiled) languages. Don't do that. Learn how to use the language the way it's supposed to be used. Go being a statically typed language, you can't have null values or a map of different data types without using type reflection and conversions.

Comment: @super you are correct, but "learn the language" is not a very helpful answer to my situation. Of course this would not be an issue if I knew the language.

Comment: @pzkpfw That's why it's a comment. It's also the only real good advice in this situation. Trying to show you how to get around this limitation might teach you a thing or two about go, but it will not teach you to write good go code so IMO you efforts are better spent on something else. Like what are the strenghts of the language.

Comment: The question is not specifically how to do exactly what I'm asking for, but also what would be a better way to approach the general problem of a data structure with multiple types where I want to print (probably iterate) existing/relevant values. The string->interface map and the current answer are both better than "learn the language", because they are constructive and give suggestions on how to proceed.

Comment: "The idea is that if I create a new instance of this struct, I'd like to be able to then only print values that are set" That is not how Go works. There simply are no "unset" struct fields. If you do not "set" them they just will be set to their zero value by the compiler/runtime and you cannot (really!) distinguish between you setting the value or the compiler.

Comment: @Volker that's fine, I don't really mind them being set to their zero value, I just want to understand what the best way is to go through them and find the ones that aren't, or if structs shouldn't be used for this use case in the first place. Judging by previous comments I'll probably look into using a map instead somehow.

Answer (score 2):

Go doesn't have builtin struct iteration. The `for ... range` statement is applicable only to:

> all entries of an array, slice, string or map, or values received on a channel

or defined types with one of those underlying types (e.g. `type Foo []int`)

If you must iterate over a struct not known at compile time, you can use the `reflect` package. To know whether a field is set or not, you can compare it to its zero value. Otherwise there is no notion of set vs. unset in a Go struct. As explained by [Volker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1266756/volker) in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66951062/iterating-over-a-struct-in-golang-and-print-the-value-if-set#comment118347240_66951062):

> [...] There simply are no "unset" struct fields. If you do not "set" them they just will be set to their zero value by the compiler/runtime and you cannot (really!) distinguish between you setting the value or the compiler.

```
type Foo struct {
  Bar string
  Baz int
  Quux []int
}

// x := Foo{"bar", 1, nil}
func printAny(x interface{}) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(x)

    for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
        field := v.Field(i)
        if !reflect.DeepEqual(field.Interface(), reflect.Zero(field.Type()).Interface()) {
            fmt.Println(field) 
            // bar
            // 1
        }
    }
}
```

...but it's slower and there are some gotchas, for example:

- `field.Interface()` panics if the field is unexported
- in the `if` clause you [can't just use the comparison operator `==`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators) because operands might be not comparable:
- you have to make sure that the zero value for field types is what you expect

---

If your goal is to *just print* the struct, you can simply implement the [`Stringer`](https://tour.golang.org/methods/17) interface, where you can do type-safe checks the way you want without `reflect`:

```
type Foo struct {
  Bar string
  Baz int
  Quux []int
}

func (f Foo) String() string {
    s := []string{f.Bar, strconv.Itoa(f.Baz)}
    if f.Quux != nil {
        s = append(s, fmt.Sprintf("%v", f.Quux))
    }
    return strings.Join(s, "\n")
}

func main() {
   fmt.Println(Foo{"bar", 1, nil}) 
   // bar
   // 1
}
```

[A Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/mjZLpD63Edf)